# NAT64 : make an IPv6-only internet host reachable from any IPv4-only internet host

Tags: ipv6

I have
Host A, who knows only IPv4
Host B, who knows only IPv6
Host C, on Ubuntu, who knows both IPv4 and IPv6

I need host C to act as a gateway between IPv4 and IPv6.
All 3 hosts are on the internet with publicly reachable addresses (IPv4 for A, IPv6 for B).

IPv6-only host will not need to connect to the IPv4-only host. What I mean is I need a translation from IPv4 to IPv6, not the contrary. A will connect to B. B will not need to connect to A.

Something like socat would be good, if it could forward port ranges (I need all ports be forwarded: 1 to 65535).

It's a 1 to 1 NAT. All traffic from host A sent to host C on address xxx(IPv4) on port P needs be forwarded to host B on address yyy(IPv6), on port P (ie same port).

I've looked at jool... still wondering how to make it work.
I've looked at tayga... still wondering if it's even well adapted to the job.

Any pointers at well-explained docs or at least docs aimed at what I'm trying to achieve would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, someone pointed out that nginx reverse proxy feature could do the trick. Good idea?

Comment: no, squid will perform better in case you want to use it as a web proxy for your browser. if you have only ipv6 and want to connect to ipv4 you need a gateway that speaks both. Moreover, the other possible chance is a 6to4 tunneling

Comment: Maybe kernel side: https://www.jool.mx/en/documentation.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question... Perhaps tnat64 could solves this problem.

Note that tnat64 can also be installed via apt-get on Debian systems.